# Access Chrome settings in Chrome Extension

Tags: browser, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking to develop a chrome extension that can access the Content Settings in [wrench] -> Options -> Under the Hood. Is that possible? I was looking on the [API page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/api_index.html) and had no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Any luck with this? I know it's almost 10 years old but hey might as well ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the language settings you're after, you can use the i18n support to get the browser language by defining different strings in each locale file, then reading it in your main script.

It doesn't look like you can obtain the font settings, not through the Chrome APIs at least.

Comment: Hello. unfortunately no - it's not the language settings... I'm looking for options that are "Under the Hood". Thank you though!