# Can a Chrome extension change Chrome settings (open in new window / popup)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, settings

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505723/access-chrome-settings-in-chrome-extension) but without a satisfying answer.
I'm trying to do change 2 chrome settings with the extension.

1. Cause the browser to open new links as tabs and not windows.
2. Cause the browser to accept pop ups from a specific URL

I have looked in the documentation, but cannot find the answer.
Could anyone help me with this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no setting to open links as tabs instead of windows. You can change the popup preference through the [`chrome.contentSettings`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings.html) API.

All of the requested features can also be enabled indirectly. Some ideas:

1. New window instead of tabs.

   1. Detect creation of tabs through [`chrome.tabs.onCreated`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onCreated).
   2. Detect whether the window was opened from inside another window:
      Use the `tab.id` property from the previous event listener to get the `window` object, using [`chrome.extension.getViews`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getViews). Then, check the `window.opener` property to determine whether the link was opened from another tab.
      *This might not work when the link has the [`rel="noreferrer"`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#link-type-noreferrer) attribute set.*
      Create a new window using [`chrome.windows.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#method-create), passing the `tabId`. The tab will be detached from its previous window, and attached to the new window.
2. You can rewrite the [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) method, which invokes [`chrome.tabs.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create) and [`chrome.windows.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#method-create) to create a new popup window.
   A global rewrite can be done by detecting page loads using [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onCreated), with `status=="complete"`, then use [`chrome.extension.getViews`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getViews) to change the `window.open` method. Make sure that you create a cached version of the `window` onject, so that the original method is still available when necessary.

These are the necessary information + documentation links which help you to create the desired functionaily. Good luck ;)

Comment: I don't see why Chrome doesn't allow devs to change user settings. Indeed, this can already be done for chrome.proxy so why not all the other settings as well?