# Change Google chrome homepage by extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there anyway to change google chrome homepage url by an extension.
I'm trying to write a simple extension which can change homepage url.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible, and a quick search reveals that such an extension [already exists](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-redirect/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna).

If you want to do it yourself, you can have a look at the [Override Pages documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override.html). You can change the `New Tab` page, and therefore can simply implement an [HTTP redirect in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/2698119) to the page you want.

Comment: I mean changing homepage url, not a new tab option.

Comment: If you mean the url of the page you go to when clicking on the home button, that's not possible. Chrome extensions can't change the users' settings. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9871636/2698119.

Comment: uhmm... About user's setting. I think Chrome extensions can change it.
Example, new tab's url.

Comment: It doesn't change the new tab url. It overrides the new tab page (which is allowed) and then uses a trick to redirect it to another url.

Answer (score 5):

Insert this code to `manifest.json`:

```
"chrome_settings_overrides": {
    "homepage": "http://www.homepage.com"
}
```

Comment: Note that this only works on Windows and Mac but not on Linux.