# How can I change the default page with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Just started to learn how to work with chrome extension, how can I use the extension to change the default page when I click on the button in the extension?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Google chrome homepage by extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235127/change-google-chrome-homepage-by-extension)

Comment: @Keith it doesn't work for me, if i use "newtab": "redirect.html" and there use window.location.replace() in script tag i stay on a blank page without redirect. And if use "homepage": "http://www.homepage.com" then nothing happens and the default chrome page opens :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In manifest v3 it worked for me:

```
    "chrome_settings_overrides": {
        "startup_pages": ["https://page.com"]
    }
```