# Offer to change the default search engine for the omnibar

Tags: google-chrome-extension, omnibox

I'm looking to offer the user (inside my Chrome Extension) the option to change their Omnibox default search engine.

Sadly, I've been unable to find any documentation on how to do something like this.  Has anyone does this before successfully?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9871636/2698119 says that "Extensions in Chrome cannot modify any of the user's settings"

Comment: @ChrisP That claim is not correct any more, I've updated the answer with a link to the [`chrome.contentSettings` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible, sadly.  See [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137079#c14) filed in Chromium

Answer (score 2):

Actually with new versions of chrome it's possible through chrome [API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override) via settings_override section. But for now it's working only on windows.

Comment: Can you give any source for "Windows-only" claim, maybe a Chromium tracker issue?

Comment: @Xan I've found info only in [chrome google groups](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/fIOJb5kXvZQ). But I've tested by myself on Linux and Mac and got message that "settings_override" is not supported for current platform.